# How to do something once

Tags: php, symfony

I’m stuck on coming up with the logic to say do this once. I need to create a ‘cart’ for the user and then use that newly created ‘cart’ to add the products that the user selected to their ‘cart’.

I’m not using SESSION variables, I know that would be a solution though.

Basically I’m trying to say this:

```
IF a User HAS a CART CREATED FOR THEM 

                then

PERSIST their SELECTED PRODUCTS to the DB in THEIR CART
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks to All.

```
/** 
 * Creates the option to 'add product to cart'.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/addToCart", name="product_addToCart")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function addToCartAction(Request $request, $id) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $product = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:Product')->find($id);
        $product->getId();
        $product->getName();
        $product->getPrice();

    // --------------------- assign added products to userCart id ------------------------ //
    $cart = new UserCart();
    $quantity = new Quantity();

        // Set Time Product was Added 
        $cart->setTimestamp(new \DateTime());
        // Set Quantity Purchased
        $quantity->setQuantity(4);
        // Set Submitted
        $cart->setSubmitted(false); 

    if ($this->checkUserLogin()) {

        $this->addFlash('notice', 'Login to create a cart');

    } else {
        $cart->setUser($this->getUser());  // Sets the User ONCE
        $cart->addQuantity($quantity);    //  Add Quantity ONCE
        $quantity->setUserCart($cart);   //   Create a UserCart ONCE
        $this->addFlash('notice', 'The product: '.$product->getName().' has been added to the cart!');
        $quantity->setProduct($product); // Sets the Product to Quantity Association ONCE
        $em->persist($product);
        $em->persist($cart);
        $em->persist($quantity); 
        $em->flush();
    }


return $this->redirectToRoute('product');

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the easiest way to do this is by simply trying to fetch the user cart, and only if one doesn't exist, creating a new one. So instead of:

```
$cart = new UserCart();
```

You'd have to write something along the lines of:

```
$cart = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:UserCart')->findOneBy([
    'user' => $this->getUser()
]);

if (!$cart) {
    $cart = new UserCart();

    // Anything else you need to do when setting up a new cart goes here
}
```

You probably want to check if the user is logged in before looking for his cart though. And remember to empty/delete the cart once the transaction has been made or canceled.